# Highlight Verified Buyers in BigCommerce Reviews

Tags: javascript, html, bigcommerce

I want to be able to highlight reviews from users that have actually purchased the item that they've reviewed (see screenshot below).
You can currently either only allow people who've purchased the item to add a review, or anyone can review, but there's no differentiation between the two.
Does anyone know if there's access to the verification process that they do when determining whether a user can post a review? I'm using my own fork of the default stencil theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

we currently don't have an anything to show verified purchase in the same way Amazon does. You can build something custom by working with a developer. The built in system does allow you to check the reviews before they are published on the storefront. And the internal review system only sends emails to those who have purchased as you stated. 
[Managing Reviews](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Managing-Reviews/?q=review&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1)

There is also an option to [use an app](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/merchandising-home/) to get more functionality.
One option might be [Trust Pilot](https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/201819697-What-does-Verified-order-mean-).

Comment: I am a developer, but have not been able to find documentation on where to begin developing that it my custom theme.

Comment: I imagine it would be to add a verification image to the reviews that have been approved before being added to the storefront. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#product-reviews You might be able build something based around this and the status. Once the status has been changed to approved, it can the be posted to the storefront with the verified checkmark. The full logic would need to be up to you. For more assistance please ask this in the BigCommerce forums https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/

Comment: Thanks, I'll see where I can get with that!